# clone svn repo with full history to local disk

Tags: svn, git-svn

I am in the process of "moving" some very large repo's from svn to git.
I know how to do it, but I need to speed up the process.

To save I/O I would like to move the svn repo to a linux box and run the conversion there.

I found this article [How to Mirror a Subversion Repository](http://wordaligned.org/articles/how-to-mirror-a-subversion-repository) and the recommended command is this one:

```
svnadmin hotcopy REPOS_PATH NEW_REPOS_PATH
```

I will execute the command on the svn server and then copy it to my local disk.
Do I need a svn server to access the repository? or can I:

```
svn git clone my-local-repo to-my-new-git-repo
```

Any tips on speeding up "git svn clone" are much appreciated

I know there a many, many questions on moving svn to git but this is about moving the svn repo to local disk before the cloning.

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Comment: Its a one time migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion provides always a local access by using a file:// URL.
This is also the smallest footprint I/O and memory wise as only the svn-client is invoked. Also this is the fastest access to a (svn)repository.

See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.basic.in-action.wc.tbl-1) for more details

On moving repositories across servers see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7669096/23264)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to speed up `git-svn` for one-time migrations is not to use it. If you need the whole history, you have to go through the history commit by commit and this simply needs ages. So if you have a local copy of the repository, you will not get any faster without throwing hardware at the process (increasing CPU and maybe RAM).

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)